# point in the interior of a square

Tags: geometry

I've got the following problem:

A point in the interior of a square ABCD is at distances 3, 4 and 5 meters from the vertices A, B and C, respectively. What is the area of ABCD?

I tried thinking about this three points forming a triangle and trying to solve the problem from there, but I didn't get any results.

Comment: I started with A=(0,h), B=(0,0), C=(h,0), $x^2+(h-y)^2=9$, $x^2+y^2=16$, $(h-x)^2+y^2=25$; subtracting the first equation from the last gives $2h(y-x)=16$, but I haven't yet reached anything neat.

Comment: And me neither ):

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\textbf{HINT:}$ Try to duplicate the square in this way

[image]

Then evaluate $\cos x$ and $\sin x$ using the cosine law on $PCQ$. That should be enough to find $l^2=CB^2$ using again the cosine law on $CBQ$.

$\textbf{Calculation details}$: 
by the cosine law on $CPQ$ we have
$$5^2=(4 \sqrt 2)^2 +3^2-2\cdot 3\cdot 4 \sqrt 2 \cos x$$
so $\cos x= \sqrt 2/3$. Then $\sin x=\sqrt 7/3$. Now let's consider the angle $\angle CQB=\pi/4+x$:
$$cos(\pi/4+x)=\cos x /\sqrt 2-\sin x/\sqrt 2=\frac{1}{3}-\frac{\sqrt 7}{3\sqrt 2}.$$
Let's now apply the cosine law on $CQB$:
$$CB^2=l^2=3^2+4^2-2\cdot 3 \cdot 4\cdot  cos(\pi/4+x)=17+4\sqrt {14}.$$

Comment: Could you explain a bit more? I'm not being able to find the answer.

Comment: Why is the angle *CQB* equal to 45?

Comment: I think I found a solution using Heron's theorem.

Comment: @EncontroRegionalSul no, it's PQB that is equal to $45$.

Comment: The key point is that PBQ is a right angle, then if follows that PQB equal to 45. To see that PBQ is a right angle notice that it is the sum of PBC and CBQ,but CBQ is equal to ABP by construction, so PBQ=PBC+ABP that is aright angle because it's the corener of the square.

Comment: I don't understand how $sin(x) = \sqrt 7 /3$ is found.

Answer (score 0):

Begin by assigning coordinates: $A = (0,L)$, $B = (0,0)$, $C = (L,0)$, $P=(X,Y)$.

Now apply Pythagoras to the three triangles with corner point $A$, $B$ and $C$:

$$X^2 +(L-Y)^2 = 9$$
$$X^2 + Y^2 = 16$$
$$(L-X)^2 + Y^2 = 25$$

Subtracting the second equation from the first leads to: $Y = (L^2 + 7)/2L$.

Subtracting the second equation from the third leads to: $X = (L^2 -9)/2L$.

Substitution of these two results into the second equation gives: $L^4 -34L^2 +65=0$.

This is a quadratic equation in $L^2$. It has the solution $L^2 = 17 + 4 \sqrt14$. This the area of the square that was sought by the OP.