# A tree stands $30$ft, $40$ft, and $50$ft from successive corners of a square garden. What is the area of the garden?

Tags: triangles, recreational-mathematics

I saw this math wrinkles this morning on Twitter and I tried to search for a solution, without luck. It comes from the Samuel Jones' book [Mathematical Wrinkles: For Teachers and Private Learners (via Amazon.com)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1330262190).

I'm not here to ask for the final solution, I actually would like to have some pointers and indicators on which formula I have to use for this.

Thanks

[image: mathematical wrinkles]

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1544719/point-in-the-interior-of-a-square).

Comment: Yes, thanks ! Nice trick :)

Comment: Ahah! True. This wrinkle is a very nice one, it gave me a bit of hard time.